# Security implications of enabling CLR on shared instance

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-clr

My database is currently isolated in its own instance and VM.  My customer is retiring that server and I need to migrate the DB to a new environment.  My DB uses CLR, so the new environment needs to have that enabled.

The customer proposed using an existing server with an existing SQLServer 2014 Standard instance hosting DBs from other software vendors on it.  I'm concerned about incurring a sort of "you break it, you bought it" liability, since I can't vouch for the security strategy of those other DBs or their front-ends.  I don't want to do something that would introduce a significant risk.

I run into similar scenarios with other customers from time to time.  I'm a database developer.  I occasionally provide DBA services pertaining to my own product for my small to medium business customers, but I am by no means a skilled DBA.  Each customer has different budgets, priorities, IT staff, and security policies, but generally none of them have IT/DBAs that can understand and/or make competent risk assessments at this level of detail.

How would enabling CLR on a shared instance affect the security of the other DBs?  (I am not asking about database-level permission_set levels, just enabling CLR itself).  I need to understand the risk (if there is any) well enough to be able to advise a 'best practice' and a customer-specific 'secure enough' alternative.

Comment: CLR was somewhat hastily removed from Azure SQL database due to an [unspecified security risk](https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/4dtjkt/ama_microsoft_databases_team_48/d1v4nbd/) - would be good if more details about that were available

Comment: @MartinSmith True, though I have my misgivings about that actually being an actual, proven risk. And even if somehow it was, then I'm not convinced that any such risk exists within the stand alone version, even though that's what was claimed as the reasoning behind adding the [ill-conceived "CLR strict security" option](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/07/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-1-clr-strict-security/) in SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that we are dealing with a shared instance, it *should* be safe to assume that none of the logins for the "customer" DBs has `sysadmin` privileges or has been granted the `CONTROL SERVER` permission.

Under such conditions, there should not be any *security* risk to having SQLCLR enabled, regardless of what many people seem to claim. Having the instance-level "CLR enabled" option enabled merely allows for a login *that has the appropriate permission* to load assemblies, and for loaded assemblies to be used by anyone granted access to the objects in those assemblies.

If users cannot load assemblies, then there can be no risk of having unknown code in assemblies, because there won't be any assemblies. Then, if one user (such as yourself) is granted the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` permission (which should be coupled with [using Certificates](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-2-clr-strict-security-solution-1/) to handle the assembly security), then only you can load assemblies.

Of course, for SQL Server 2005 - 2016, and for SQL Server 2017 and newer that has the "CLR strict security" instance-level configuration option *dis*abled, the database owner (i.e. the `dbo` user) and any user in the `db_owner` fixed database role *can* create `SAFE` assemblies, but those aren't a *security* risk. Sure, they might be a performance risk, but the same is true for sloppy data modeling, T-SQL, triggers, etc. If the various vendors are not `dbo` for their databases, then this is a non-issue. If the vendors are `dbo` for their respective databases *and* the desire is to prevent them creating `SAFE` assemblies, it is easy enough to create an instance-wide DDL trigger for the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` statement and issue a `ROLLBACK` if the user is not you and/or it is not executed within your database.

If someone is a member of the `sysadmin` instance-level role, or granted the `CONTROL SERVER` instance-level permission, then they can also load assemblies. BUT, and here is what most "security" related recommendations miss: having "CLR enabled" disabled does *not* protect against someone who is a `sysadmin` or has `CONTROL SERVER` permission because *they have permission to enable the "CLR enabled" option* (and enable `xp_cmdshell`, etc and do whatever they want)!

There is no *inherent* risk in having this option enabled because having it enabled does not give anyone the permission to load assemblies that pose a security risk (in SQL Server 2005 - 2016, `dbo` and users in `db_owner` role can load `SAFE` assemblies). And, once loaded, assemblies marked as `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` or `UNSAFE` need additional security (i.e. Certificates / strong naming, *not* `TRUSTWORTHY`) in order for their code to be executed. And, starting in SQL Server 2017 *all* assemblies, by default, need that additional security just to be loaded in the first place. *And*, that additional security (for the operation of the assembly) requires `sysadmin` level permissions:

- In the [unfortunate case of someone setting the database to `TRUSTWORTHY ON`](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/12/30/please-please-please-stop-using-impersonation-execute-as/), the login that owns the DB needs to have either the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` or `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission (for SQL Server 2017+ with "CLR strict security" enabled — the default — it must be `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY`), which can only be granted by a sysadmin (these permissions are obviously implied if the owning login is a `sysadmin`). Hopefully vendor DBs would never have `TRUSTWORTHY` enabled.
- When assemblies are signed, a certificate or asymmetric key needs to be created in the `[master]` DB, then a login needs to be created from that, then that login needs to be granted either the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` or `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission (for SQL Server 2017+ with "CLR strict security" enabled — the default — it must be `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY`).

For some examples of handling SQLCLR security, please see:

- [Stairway to SQLCLR Level 3: Security (General and SAFE Assemblies)](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/stairway-to-sqlclr-level-3-security-general-and-safe-assemblies)
- [Stairway to SQLCLR Level 4: Security (EXTERNAL and UNSAFE Assemblies)](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/stairway-to-sqlclr-level-4-security-external-and-unsafe-assemblies)

That being said, as David Browne noted in a comment on this answer:

> Another important point is about the trust that presumably exists among the stakeholders for the various databases. In a corporate environment, everyone is expected to be trustworthy and cooperative. in a 3rd party hosting environment, you have to assume that the owner of the adjacent workload is a completely untrusted and even malicious actor. Lots of not-perfectly-safe things are safe-enough to do behind a firewall and among friends.

Comment: @MartinSmith For SQL Server 2005 - 2016, it would only be `SAFE` assemblies -- unless they are granted `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` or `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` or any permission that implies those, and that is only if `TRUSTWORTHY` is enabled. For SQL Server 2017 and newer (until they fix this hideous mess), the `SAFE` assemblies are no longer accepted without the extra permission, and `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` is the permission needed for all assemblies, even if they aren't marked as `UNSAFE`. I will update my answer to be clearer about that. Thanks!

Comment: Another important point is about the trust that presumably exists among the stakeholders for the various databases.  In a corporate environment, everyone is expected to be trustworthy and cooperative.  in a 3rd party hosting environment, you have to assume that the owner of the adjacent workload is a completely untrusted and even malicious actor.  Lots of not-perfectly-safe things are safe-enough to do behind a firewall and among friends.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Good point. I will mention it in my update.

Comment: >Given that we are dealing with a shared instance, it should be safe to assume that none of the owners of the "customer" DBs has sysadmin privileges or has been granted the CONTROL SERVER permission.

I didn't want to complicate my question with the gory details, but you'd be surprised.  I was being generous by implying with "different security policies" that my customers all have one.  Today, for example, I was _emailed_ the sa password for the server in question.  And let's just say it wasn't something I couldn't have guessed within 50 tries.

Comment: @KevinP emailed the sa password? Oh my. Well, no need to worry about security when no such thing exists in the universe ;-). I see that you have already accepted (thanks) and I have not yet finished my updates (please see my reply to Martin a few comments above this one for some of it), but I was focused on newer SQL Server but in 2014 the DB owner could create a SAFE assembly, though that is not a _security_ risk. I should have the update done within the hour.

Comment: Given a murky, sketchy, all-or-nothing security environment, maybe the question then becomes, "Is enabling CLR the only sysadmin/control_server privilege keeping the barbarians at bay?"  I think your answer would be "no", because a limited user, especially one using an account created for front-end client connections, would likely (hopefully) not have explicit permission to load assemblies.  I understand that I have to trust that my customer is not doling out the sa login to just _anybody_.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky.  Thanks, I did see the exchange between you and Martin.  I look forward to your update!  Your initial answer is good enough for my immediate need.  I can advise the customer to review login usage and revoke permissions as needed (and change the sa password!!).  Then I can proceed with enabling CLR.

Comment: @KevinP I think I fixed it all up. Please review. Also, yes, hopefully app logins are low-privilege. If they are `dbo` then they might be able to create `SAFE` assemblies (in SQL Server 2005 - 2016, or in 2017+ with "CLR strict security" *dis*abled), but as I pointed out, if that's the case and considered undesirable, a DDL trigger is easy to implement to prevent that from happening. Also, for `EXTERNAL ACCESS` and `UNSAFE` assemblies in 2005-2016 or all assemblies in 2017+, the assemblies need to be signed and Certificate(s) installed. Lemme know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks @SolomonRutzky for the extra detail and for the links.  I was initially confused by the assembly permissions, but I had an epiphany- `SAFE` is not a descriptive property of an assembly, assigned by an authorized user and entailing special rights, like a mayor bestowing the 'key to the city' on a proven worthy citizen.  Rather, they are instructions to the DB engine that set max exec boundaries, like a mother telling the babysitter not to leave Johnny alone with the paste- "keep him safe!"  Thinking about it that way makes it easier to understand what exposure `ENABLE CLR` creates.

Comment: @KevinP Yes, the permission set levels are boundaries for maximum allowed functionality / permissions. The 2 "Stairway to SQLCLR..." links at the bottom of my answer go into more detail on the various restrictions. The formatting got a little messed up when they re-did the site so the first chart in Level 4 actually scrolls to the right (originally the table adjusted and there was no scrolling).